# How to run Electron with Angular?

Tags: angular, electron

How to run Electron with Angular?

I had some problems to run Electron with Angular, so I shared my way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Resources

1. [Writing Your First Electron App](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app).
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RV868-R4F2Y&t=30s (based on this video).

### Step by step

Create a new Angular project (I did it with Webstrom):

```
ng new electron-with-angular --defaults
```

Install Electron:

```
npm install --save-dev electron
```

Create a main.js file (in the project directory, not in the src directory).

Copy basic main.js from resource 1.

In main.js - change the following line to:

```
  win.loadFile('dist/YOUR_PROJECT/index.html')
```

In index.file - change the following line to:

```
  <base href="./">
```

In package.json - change the following lines to (I add an image for clarification):

```
  "main": "main.js",
```

In the scripts:

```
"electron": "ng build && electron ."
```

[image]

Run the following command in the terminal:

```
npm run electron
```